# Connecting to Docker Daemon from jenkins running inside a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I have a jenkins running inside a docker container and a docker running inside a different docker container.

I have map the /var/run/docker.sock file of local machine to the docker container and am able to execute docker commands inside docker container. Both the docker container and jenkins container are on the same network. But while connecting to docker container from jenkins, am getting connection refused. I have given 666 permissions to /var/run/docker.sock file but yet am not able to connect between the two. Both the container can ping each other sucessfully.

Comment: This sounds like an unusual setup; running a separate Docker daemon in a container is generally discouraged.  Can you provide an [mcve] to clarify what exactly you're running?

Comment: I am planning to build a devops pipeline, with each of the tool on the separate container. I have one integration server where jenkins is installed, one docker server where I want  to build image and push it to dockerhub and one deployment server where image will be pulled from dockerhub and deployed to production systems. But am unable to connect between jenkins and docker container, reasons are stated in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

You could connect to the [Docker in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) environment over `tcp` or by sharing the `docker` socket between the containers.

---

This example is with everything in `docker` orchestrated using `docker-compose`.

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── Dockerfile
├── etc
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── default.conf
└── plugins.txt
```

The `docker-compose.yaml` sets up `jenkins` behind `nginx` and a `docker:20.10.5-dind` service.

### tcp

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:1.19'
    container_name: 'nginx'
    restart: 'always'
    depends_on:
    - 'jenkins'
    ports:
    - '80:80'
    volumes:
    - 'jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    - './etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: '.'
    container_name: 'jenkins'
    restart: 'always'
    expose:
    - '50000'
    - '8080'
    environment:
    - 'DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376'
    - 'DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client'
    - 'DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1'
    volumes:
    - 'jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    - 'certs:/certs:ro'
  docker:
    image: 'docker:20.10.5-dind'
    container_name: 'docker'
    privileged: true
    volumes:
    - 'certs:/certs'
volumes:
  jenkins:
  certs:
```

**Note**: the `docker` client certificates are shared between the `docker` and the `jenkins` containers and the environment is set in the `jenkins` container to connect to the `docker` service.

The [`nginx` config is slightly modified from the doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-nginx/):

```
upstream jenkins {
  keepalive 32;
  server jenkins:8080 max_fails=3;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
server {
  listen *:80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name _;

  charset utf-8;
  ignore_invalid_headers off;

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
    rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
  }
  location /userContent {
    root /var/jenkins_home/;
    if (!-f $request_filename){
      rewrite (.*) /$1 last;
      break;
    }
    sendfile on;
  }
  location / {
    sendfile off;
    proxy_pass         http://jenkins;
    proxy_redirect     default;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header   Connection        $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;
    proxy_buffering            off;
    proxy_request_buffering    off;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
  }
}
```

The `jenkins` service is a custom built image pre-baked with the `docker` client and the default suggested `jenkins` plugins plus the [Docker](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) and [Docker Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) plugins:

```docker
FROM docker:20.10.5-dind as docker
FROM jenkins/jenkins:alpine
USER root
COPY --from=docker /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
USER jenkins
```

```
github:1.33.1
pipeline-model-api:1.8.4
scm-api:2.6.4
mailer:1.32.1
workflow-support:3.8
font-awesome-api:5.15.2-2
pipeline-milestone-step:1.3.2
git:4.6.0
plain-credentials:1.7
resource-disposer:0.15
jackson2-api:2.12.1
jquery3-api:3.5.1-3
gradle:1.36
credentials:2.3.15
docker-workflow:1.26
workflow-scm-step:2.12
display-url-api:2.3.4
bootstrap4-api:4.6.0-2
antisamy-markup-formatter:2.1
command-launcher:1.5
pipeline-stage-tags-metadata:1.8.4
snakeyaml-api:1.27.0
pipeline-stage-view:2.19
script-security:1.76
okhttp-api:3.14.9
pipeline-stage-step:2.5
workflow-step-api:2.23
timestamper:1.11.8
pipeline-github-lib:1.0
token-macro:2.13
pam-auth:1.6
workflow-cps-global-lib:2.18
ws-cleanup:0.39
pipeline-model-definition:1.8.4
workflow-aggregator:2.6
jsch:0.1.55.2
matrix-auth:2.6.5
ssh-credentials:1.18.1
ant:1.11
jjwt-api:0.11.2-9.c8b45b8bb173
momentjs:1.1.1
trilead-api:1.0.13
durable-task:1.35
workflow-job:2.40
git-server:1.9
ssh-slaves:1.31.5
plugin-util-api:2.0.0
git-client:3.6.0
lockable-resources:2.10
checks-api:1.5.0
pipeline-input-step:2.12
cloudbees-folder:6.15
pipeline-build-step:2.13
popper-api:1.16.1-2
pipeline-graph-analysis:1.10
matrix-project:1.18
workflow-api:2.41
github-branch-source:2.9.7
workflow-basic-steps:2.23
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.13-1.0
workflow-multibranch:2.22
workflow-cps:2.90
ldap:1.26
build-timeout:1.20
echarts-api:5.0.1-1
pipeline-model-extensions:1.8.4
structs:1.22
junit:1.48
docker-java-api:3.1.5.2
docker-plugin:1.2.2
workflow-durable-task-step:2.38
credentials-binding:1.24
jdk-tool:1.5
bouncycastle-api:2.20
docker-commons:1.17
github-api:1.123
authentication-tokens:1.4
email-ext:2.82
branch-api:2.6.2
pipeline-rest-api:2.19
ace-editor:1.1
handlebars:1.1.1
```

After the initial `jenkins` setup, create the X.509 Client Certificate Server Credentials then configure the Docker Cloud with the `docker` service using `tcp`.
[image: docker cloud tcp]

**Note**: you can get the client cert, client key and server ca cert for creating the X.509 Client Certificate Server Credentials using the below commands:

```
docker exec docker cat /certs/client/key.pem
docker exec docker cat /certs/client/cert.pem
docker exec docker cat /certs/server/ca.pem
```

### socket

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:1.19'
    container_name: 'nginx'
    restart: 'always'
    depends_on:
    - 'jenkins'
    ports:
    - '80:80'
    volumes:
    - 'jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    - './etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: '.'
    container_name: 'jenkins'
    restart: 'always'
    expose:
    - '50000'
    - '8080'
    volumes:
    - 'jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    - 'socket:/var/run'
  docker:
    image: 'docker:20.10.5-dind'
    container_name: 'docker'
    privileged: true
    volumes:
    - 'socket:/var/run'
volumes:
  jenkins:
  socket:
```

**Note**: the `docker` socket is shared between the `docker` and the `jenkins` containers in the `socket` volume.

By default the `docker` socket is owned by `root:root`, the `jenkins` user is not able to connect to the shared socket, you can change the sockets group ownership to the GID of the `jenkins` user: `docker exec docker chown 0:1000 /var/run/docker.sock`.

After the initial `jenkins` setup configure the Docker Cloud with the `docker` service using the shared `unix` socket.
[image: docker cloud unix]