# Unable to build docker images in Jenlins pipeline; docker not found

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build my docker images as part of Jenkins pipeline.
The Jenkins is running as docker `jenkins/jenkins:lts`.
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v $(pwd)/jenkins-file:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins-my --privileged jenkins/jenkins:lts`

The Jenkinsfile looks like following:

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Docker Build") {
            agent any
            steps {
                echo "building the application..... "
                sh 'docker build -t content-service:1.0 .'
            }
        }

        stage("test") {
            steps {
                echo "testing the application....."
            }
        }

        stage("deploy") {
            steps {
                echo "deploying the application....."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Docker Build stage fails with following error

```
building the application..... 
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t content-service:1.0 .
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/my-pipeline_main@2@tmp/durable-751e98d7/script.sh: 1: **docker: not found**
```

I have docker plugin installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZV83.png)

Can you please let me what is missing, I am new to Jenkins, please let me know what should I do to resolve this issue.

I searched internet and installed the docker plugin.
I also added the Docker agent under Manage Jenkins --> Configure Clouds. but did not help.

I have followed these posts but did not help
[Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850565/docker-not-found-when-building-docker-image-using-docker-jenkins-container-pipel)

Comment: You're missing the `docker` binary on the agent. I have a complete (albeit a little outdated) example https://stackoverflow.com/a/66508685/1423507

Comment: Let me try this, I did try installing docker inside my jenkins docker and mounted /var/run/docker.sock inside it. But I started getting 
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/jenkins-my/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: This is also explained in my other post, when using the `docker` socket, by default the `docker` socket is owned by `root:root`, the `jenkins` user is not able to connect to the shared socket, you can change the sockets group ownership to the GID of the `jenkins` user: `docker exec docker chown 0:1000 /var/run/docker.sock`.

Comment: @masseyb I am still getting the same problem despite that I have valid connection to docker container.
Docker Compose file:
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: 'jenkins/jenkins:lts'
    container_name: 'jenkins-my'
    restart: 'always'
    expose:
    - '50000'
    - '8080'
    ports:
    - 50000:50000
    - 8080:8080
    volumes:
    - jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
    - socket:/var/run
  docker:
    image: 'docker:20.10.5-dind'
    container_name: 'docker'
    privileged: true
    volumes:
    - 'socket:/var/run'
volumes
  jenkins:
    driver: local
  socket

Comment: yay!! Finally got it working, The missing part was 
volumes:
 - '/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker'

Thanks a lot @masseyb

Comment: Can mount the `docker` cli from the host as you're doing, or install it in the container image. There is more than one way to do it.